# Autoloading Problem in Object-Oriented PHP Program

Tags: php, autoload

Good afternoon to everyone.

For the past 3 days, I've been struggling with PHP's Autoloading features, which aims to simplify and unify a program's class files, all located in one executing file. For the context, I am currently learning the OOP perspective of PHP from [this tutorial videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0eyrZgxdwhypQiZnYXM7z7-OTkcMgGPh) to not only further understand PHP's OOP understanding before doing a PHP OOP project from college, but also to try to create my own PHP program, so do ELI5 about the solution to me, please.

From what I've learned from the following videos: [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3pZdmJ64jo&list=PL0eyrZgxdwhypQiZnYXM7z7-OTkcMgGPh&index=9) and [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCHWAyUDXik), the autoload codes I written from what I've learned appears to work fine, however, it gave two warnings:

> Warning: include(/classes/person.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\autoloader.php on line 12

> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/classes/person.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\autoloader.php on line 12

And, it gave a fatal error message as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'person' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\index.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\index.php on line 33

I will include [downloadable files](https://www.php-forum.com/phpforum/download/file.php?id=758) so that anyone check and verify it with me.

The Autoloader codes on the autoloading file:

```html
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    include str_replace("\\","/","\classes").'/'.str_replace('\\',"/",$className).'.php';
});

?>
```

Simple executing codes on the index file:

```html
<?php

$person1 = new person();
$person1->SetName("Kai");
echo $person1->name;

?>
```

My questions: what's wrong, how to create a functioning autoload feature, and are there any additional corrections that can be made from my program?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to your path, as well as the sub folder in that folderwhich contains your app.

```php
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // This is the folder you serve files from
    $file .= '/CollegeTimetableApp' // This is the folder in which your app lives
    $file .= str_replace("\\", "/", "\classes"); 
    $file .= '/'; // Consider using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead
    $file .= str_replace('\\', "/", $className);
    $file .= '.php';
    include $file;
});

?>
```

Comment: I found this one autoloading codes from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#120258. I used it to replace the code I previously wrote and yet, it displayed an error like this: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'vehicle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\index.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\index.php on line 39. I don't understand the meaning of this error, can you elaborate it for me? Thank you so much.

Comment: It means that the autoloader is expecting the class `vehicle` to be defined in the file mentioned in the error message. More than likely the autoloader is looking in the wrong place. Did the code I posted not work for you? If you could share any error messages you receive it would really help with figuring this out

Comment: To tell the truth, the code scripts you posted didn't work. It displayed two warnings: Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/classes/vehicle.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\autoloader.php on line 12 and Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/classes/vehicle.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeTimetableApp\includes\autoloader.php on line 12

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include `CollegeTimetableApp` which seems to be where your files are located, as well as add comments as to what each line does

Comment: Your edited code scripts worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem